# Copy and paste cell to the next column based on a condition

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to paste the cell contents based on a condition that if there is no match then copy the first word of the cell and paste it to the next cell to the right but it gives me object not defined error.

CENTRUM ADVANCE TABLET should copy only CENTRUM

Below is my code

```
Sub splitUpRegexPattern()

Dim re As Object, c As Range
Dim allMatches
Dim cell As Object
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

For Each cell In Selection
    count = count + 1
Next cell
' MsgBox count & " item(s) selected"

Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(m?g|mcg|ml|IU|MIU|mgs|µg|gm|microg|microgram)\b)"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global = True

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("D2", ActiveSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Cells ' Select the range and run the code
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(c.Value)
    If allMatches.count > 0 Then
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = allMatches(0)
    Else
        Selection.Copy
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value.Paste
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: So whats the problem

Comment: It wont work. Gives me Object not defined error in the else section of the code.

Comment: do you simply mean c.Copy? Rather than Selection.Copy?

Comment: will c.Copy work since I tried that too, how do I copy just the first word of the cell into the next cell to the right.

Comment: See @CtznKane525 answer. Haven't checked the regex part but c.Copy should handle the object error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Work with split function, Example*

```
Set allMatches = re.Execute(c.Value)
If allMatches.count > 0 Then
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = allMatches(0)
Else
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Split(c.Value, " ")(0)
End If
```

*[Split Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)*

> **`Split (text_string, delimiter, limit, compare)`**

**`text_string:`** Would be **`C.Value`**.

***`delimiter:`*** delimiter would be space character (" ").

***`limit:`*** leave the `limit` argument blank because we need to separate out all the words from `C.Value`.

***`compare:`*** This would be blank, as blank specifies binary comparison method.

Answer (score 1):

A couple changes I believe you need to make:

```
c.Copy
c.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
```

There's no paste property of a value. c is a Range so it has Copy and Paste methods.

For your other question:

```
Dim LArray() As String
LArray = Split(c.Text, " ")
c.Offset(0, 1).Item(1, 1).Value = LArray(0)
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I copy just the first word till the space? CENTRUM ADVANCE TABLET should copy only CENTRUM

Comment: Get the text property of the range...split it...get the first instance and assign it to the text property of the offsets first cell...I can give code later...but that's an entirely different question

Comment: updated...ideally follow ups should be a sep question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Else
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
```

Comment: this went into a continuous loop.

Comment: I didn't look at the rest of your code, that just fixed the pasting issue